# Is there a 'generic colouriser' port for powershell?

Tags: regex, color, powershell

I'm using 'generic colouriser' aka `grc` or `grcat` on Linux. I'm searching for a similar tool that can be used with powershell.

Most implementations are not as powerful as grc.
Here are some examples:

- [colorize-row](http://scriptolog.blogspot.de/2007/09/colorize-matching-output-in-pipeline.html) from Shay Levy => colorizes a row in format-table

  - selectable column
  - selectable color
  - uses regexp
- [format-color](http://www.bgreco.net/powershell/format-color/)

  - uses a hashtable: key=pattern; value=color
  - uses regexp (-match) and simple match (-like)
  - it's not pipelined